# Rundeck Tomcat - HTTP 403 error accessing localhost:8080/rundeck with admin credentials

Tags: tomcat, war, rundeck

I have installed rundeck via WAR file on Linux/Tomcat and I am having issues to login into the /rundeck.
I am getting a 403 error when logging in localhost:8080/rundeck saying that access has been denied.

When installed via WAR on Tomcat, should I configure tomcat-users.xml or realm.properties?
I could see this issue #620 but it was not clear for me if I need to configure just the tomcat-users.xml or if I am missing any other step.

tomcat-users.xml file

I am not able to login using the credentials defined at tomcat-users.xml file, but I can login with the credentials defined at real.properties file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="user"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="user" password="user" roles="user"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,user,manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

real.properties file

```
administrador:administrador,user,admin,manage-gui
usuario:usuario,user
```

admin.aclpolicy

```
description: Admin, all access.
context:
  project: '.*' # all projects
for:
  resource:
    - allow: '*' # allow read/create all kinds
  adhoc:
    - allow: '*' # allow read/running/killing adhoc jobs
  job: 
    - allow: '*' # allow read/write/delete/run/kill of all jobs
  node:
    - allow: '*' # allow read/run for all nodes
by:
  group: admin

---

description: Admin, all access.
context:
  application: 'rundeck'
for:
  resource:
    - allow: '*' # allow create of projects
  project:
    - allow: '*' # allow view/admin of all projects
  project_acl:
    - allow: '*' # allow admin of all project-level ACL policies
  storage:
    - allow: '*' # allow read/create/update/delete for all /keys/* storage content
by:
  group: admin
```

framework.properties file

```
framework.server.name = 10.188.25.96
framework.server.hostname = 10.188.25.96
framework.server.port = 8080
framework.server.url = http://10.188.25.96:8080/rundeck
```

rundeck.properties file

```
grails.serverURL=http://10.188.25.96:8080/rundeck
server.servlet.context-path=/rundeck
```

Rundeck version: rundeck-3.4.6-20211110 (Tomcat version Apache Tomcat/8.5.73)
install type: WAR
OS Name/version: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP1
DB Type/version: h2

Expected Behavior
Successfully login to localhost:8080/rundeck

How to Reproduce
Install the rundeck via WAR file in Tomcat and try to login to localhost:8080/rundeck.
A HTTP Status 403 is displayed as "Access to the requested resource has been denied".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I replicated your environment and it works, which user are you using to log in?

Comment: Hi MegaDrive68k, I tried logging on rundeck using adminstrador/administrador and usuario/usuario.

I can logging with both, but not able to modify/create anything at rundeck.

Comment: Could you share the `catalina.out` (with all stack trace) file output at the moment of receiving the 403 error? Thanks!

Comment: Sir, I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was creating a rundeck folder outsite the tomcat rundeck folder that was automatically been created from the WAR file. Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: Great! Please post your solution as a answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I was creating a rundeck folder outsite the tomcat rundeck folder that was automatically been created from the WAR file.

Using the rundeck folder created inside webapps/ solved the issue.